# Find unused resource files (.jsp, .xhtml, images) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, file

I'm developing a large web application in **Eclipse** and some of the resources (I'm talking about files, **NOT code**) are getting deprecated, however, I don't know which are and I'm including them in my ending war file.

I know Eclipse recognizes file paths into its directory because I can access the link to an image or other page while I'm editing one of my *xhtml* pages (using <kbd>Control</kbd>). But is there a way to localize the unused resources in order to remove them?

Answer (score 3):

Following these 3 steps would work for sites with a relatively finite number of dynamic pages:

1. Install your site on a filesystem `mount`'ed with `atime` (access time).
2. Try harvesting the whole site with `wget`.
3. Use `find` to see which files were not accessed recently.

Done.

Answer (score 2):

As I know Eclipse doesn't have this (need this too).

I'm using grep in conjuction with bash scripting - shell script takes files in my resource folder, put filenames in list, greping throught source code for every record in the list and if grep find it it is removed.

At the end list is printed on console - just unused resources retain in the list.

Comment: Do you have the script around there? Just to make an idea.

Answer (score 1):

[UCDetector](http://www.ucdetector.org/) might be your best bet, specifically, the [custom](http://www.ucdetector.org/custom.html) marker aspects of this tool.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse I have not found a way. I have used the following shell command script.

**Find .ftl template files which are NOT referenced in .java files**

```
cd myfolder
find . -name "*.ftl" -printf "%f\n" |while read fname; do  grep --include \*.java -rl "$fname" . > /dev/null || echo "${fname} not referenced" ;  done;
```

or

**Find all .ftl template files which are NOT referenced in .java, .ftl, .inc files**

```
cd myfolder
find . -name "*.ftl" -printf "%f\n" |while read fname; do  grep --include \*.java --include \*.ftl --include \*.inc -rl "$fname" . > /dev/null || echo "${fname} not referenced" ;  done;
```

Note: on MacOSX you can use `gfind` instead of `find` in case `-printf` is not working.

**Example output**

```
productIndex2.ftl not referenced
showTestpage.ftl not referenced
```